# What is using my bandwidth on Windows 10 since creators update?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-10-v1703

Since opting into the stable channel of the creators update, something has been constantly using between 800k and 1.5Mbps. All the time. I can see this from the "performance" tab, but it's not shown in processes, app history or the new windows 10 network usage pie chart.

I've tried netstat, NetLimiter, SysInternals Suite's procmon and procexplorer as found on related StackOverflow threads and NONE of them are showing anything, not even the "hidden" tab of ProcExplorer.

I've run MalwareBytes and Windows Antivirus scans in case some kind of filesharing malware was on the machine, but in that case surely it would be UPLOADS taking the bandwidth, not downloads.

The only clue I have is that about once every 30 minutes, a window flashes up very very quickly. Might something be trying to update itself and constantly failing?

Given that 1Mb is a quarter of my 4Mb broadband speed, I'd like to try and track this down.

[image: Resource monitor]

[image: Screenshot of bandwidth usage]

Comment: Check in Resource Monitor? It should be available at the bottom of your task manager window and will give more details on what is using the network.

Comment: Tried that. Everything is sitting at "zero" while the graph (above) is showing constant traffic.

Comment: Can you correllate this with CPU activity? is there a service/process that is going around the same time. have you disabled the peer to peer update setting?

Comment: Everything at zero in res mon? That can't be right, there will always be some activity on W10. What is listed in TCP connections and listening ports?

Comment: Julian: Yes - see added screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5uao.png). Resmon is sitting with a few bytes showing, right next to it is network usage with 944k!
@StevenDavison : If you meant "distributed windows update sharing", yes, that was already off. Toggled it just in case, but it's definitely off.

Comment: Shot in the dark...could be a hardware level issue. Might be worth checking for updated BIOS or WiFi adapter drivers.

Comment: OK, this is weird. I tried a different USB socket and updated driver for the UBS-Wifi adaptor and still it used data. Then tried an ethernet cable and suddenly it's back to normal. Zero idle traffic. Ethernet cable not long term practical solution, but I wonder what is making THIS wifi connection report constant traffic, when my Win 10 laptop wifi connection is not reporting that? So, the immediate problem is at least identified... but.. any ideas?

Comment: Use better tools to determine which process is using bandwidth.  Your current toolset is poorly equiped to do that.

Comment: use a HTTP proxy (Charles, Fiddler) to see which network activity you have

Comment: Try a program like Wireshark, which captures all network traffic, and see what addresses it says you are communicating with.

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue. got a comcast notice that i was about to hit my data cap. checked windows 10 bandwith usage, 2tb "system" used from 5/1 - 5/17. a temporary fix was to run .CMD as admin, then type:

net stop wuauserv

this would stop the update services. although, i found if i set my ethernet connection to metered (also disabled one drive at startup) it seems to have fixed the problem.